# Given a point on a level set, is there a unique tangent line at that point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Given a point on a level set, is there a unique tangent line at that point?

Can someone help me to understand this question?

Comment: Do you know what a level set is? Because if you don't, then you have little hope of understanding the question, and close to none of solving it. So I would start there.

Comment: as i know, the level set of a function $f(x_1, ... ,x_n)$ is the set $\{(x_1, ... , x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n} ; f(x_1, ... ,x_n) = c\}$ where f(x_1, ... ,x_n) is a function that goes from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What happens if you take $f(x,y) = y-|x|$, for example?

Comment: as an answer to Greg Martin: if i take the level set $f(x,y) = 0$, then i have $y = |x|$ which has multiples tangent lines at $(0,0)$. Am I right?

Comment: It doesn't have any tangent line. What hypotheses do you have about $f$?

Comment: yeah, don't have any, u right. i don't have more hypothesis about f. But that counterexample answers my question. Thanks